# Why does the value in array in my python code changes to 0 after using array once?

Tags: python, arrays

So I am writing a python code where I have an array of elements and I am using counting sort on it! So I am creating a count array, where the first value contains the value from [1,200] and the second value counts the occurrence in my array. I have created a function SortedArray(count_array,d) d is the number of elements that will sorted array contain.

```
def sortedarray(array,d):
    a=[0]*d
    i=0
    for j in range(d):
        if array[j][1]>0:
            while array[j][1]>0:
                a[i]=array[j][0]
                array[j][1]-=1
                i+=1
    return a
```

this is my remaining code which is trying to create a count array and use it.

```
def activityNotifications(expenditure, d):
    L = queue.Queue(maxsize=d)
    for i in range(d):
        L.put(expenditure[i])
    count_array=[[i+1,0] for i in range(200)]

    for a in L.queue:
        j=0
        while(j<200):
            if a==count_array[j][0]:
                count_array[j][1]+=1
                break
            j+=1
    #1 print(list(sortedarray(count_array,d)))        
    medi=median(sortedarray(count_array,d),d)

    #2 print(medi,list(L.queue),list(sortedarray(count_array,d)),expenditure[d])
    notifications=0
    if expenditure[d]>=2*medi:
        notifications=1

    for x in range(d,len(expenditure)):
        L.get()
        L.put(expenditure[x])
        j=0
        while(j<200):
            if count_array[j][0]==expenditure[d-x]:
                count_array[j][1]-=1
            if L.queue[d-1]==count_array[j][0]:
                count_array[j][1]+=1
                break
            j+=1
        medi=median(sortedarray(count_array,d),d)
        if expenditure[d]>=2*medi:
            notifications+=1
        print(list(L.queue),sortedarray(count_array,d),expenditure[d])
    return notifications
```

So I have marked above two print statements with #1 and #2. Since I was getting the wrong values, I wanted to see where exactly am I getting wrong values and I noticed this when I use my sortedarray() funtion on count_array. It returns right output at the first call but if I call it again the values returned are all zero that is in the second print statement! Why is this happening since I did not change count_array in between those print statements, just used my sortedarray() function twice but it should not change the count_array array right?

Comment: `array[j][1]-=1` - that's changing the input.

Comment: check the position of my print statements. The output is being changed there only when I have not even used the above statement you mentioned. Between the two print statements I marked with comments #1 and #2. The value of count_array changes from original to all zero.

Comment: "The output is being changed there only when I have not even used the above statement you mentioned." - but you did. You called `sorted_array` between the two `print` calls, and `sorted_array` contains the `array[j][1]-=1` line.

Comment: You also called `sorted_array` as part of the arguments to the `print` calls.

Comment: Ohh. yes. Thanks for pointing out the mistake, I can close this question down if you can answer it!